# Nova linha em PHP na função fopen

Tags: php, fopen

Bom pessoal, eu estava seguindo uma apostila de PHP e ate aqui tudo bem, mas o problema esta em gravar os dados em um bloco de notas do windows, ao invés de ele dar nova linha "\n", ele esta colocando os dados uns atras dos outros como se não desse enter, vou postar o código e desde já obrigado pela ajuda de vocês...

```
$texto = $date."\t".$tireqty." Pneus \t".$oilqty." Oleo \t "
.$sparkqty." Plugues de velas \t $".$totalamount."\t".$address."\n";

if($arquivo = fopen("carteirainter.txt", 'ab'))
{
    fputs($arquivo, $texto."\n");
    fclose($arquivo);
}
else
    echo "Não foi possivel efetuar a gravaçao.<br>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a constante PHP_EOL:

```
fputs($arquivo, $texto.PHP_EOL);
```

Alternativamente, pode forçar desse modo:

```
fputs($arquivo, $texto."
");
```

Outro modo é usar o **carriage return** \r juntamente com o **newline** \n:

```
fputs($arquivo, $texto."\r\n");
```

Recomenda-se que o ambiente esteja usando um conjunto de caracteres UTF8.

Observação adicional sobre compatibilidade do *carriage return* e *newline*:

```
\n -> linux
\r -> Mac
\n -> Mac OS-X
\r\n -> Windows
```

Comment: pdf tocar no assunto?